# Cómo convertir texto a elemento DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Tengo una cadena que contiene código HTML que deseo pasar a un nodo HTML para así poder editarlo como muestro a continuación:

```
var code = '<p class="c1">Hola mundo</p>';
// Código para convertir
code.className="c";
document.body.appendChild(code);
```

¿Cómo debería hacerlo?

Comment: Una opción es añadir primero el elemento y luego usar el DOM, ej: `document.body.innerHTML = '<p class="c1">Hola mundo</p>';
document.body.firstChild.className = "c"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Estás realizando mal la llamada a `appendChild()`, ya que debes pasar por parámetro un elemento y no una cadena de caracteres.

Una manera de hacerlo sería:

```js
var code = '<p class="c1">Hola mundo</p>';
/* Creamos un contenedor para el HTML de nuestra variable */
let contenedor = document.createElement("div");
/* Insertamos el HTML en el elemento recién creado */
contenedor.innerHTML = code;
/* Ahora hacemos que tu variable "code" sea el primer hijo del contenedor */
code = contenedor.firstChild;
// Código para convertir
code.className = "c";
/* Agregamos al DOM tu elemento */
document.body.appendChild(code);
```

Para empezar he creado un contenedor con [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) al que asignaremos el HTML de nuestro código.

Al hacerlo el primer hijo del contenedor será el elemento que deseas editar (en mi código he sobreescrito la variable `code`, pero yo no usaría la variable como intermedia para contener una cadena de caracteres).

Por último, ya tienes tu variable `code` preparada para agregarla al DOM del documento o modificar lo que desees de ella (como la clase).

Comment: Donde esta el //comentario se supone que debería haber un código que convierte la variable a un nodo html, pero no hay ninguna función que satisfaga la necesidad? O solo se puede de la manera (forzosa) que sería creando un elemento nodo?

Comment: No, no hay ninguna función nativa que convierta un código HTML a un nodo, ya que se supone que todo HTML debería estar contenido siempre por un elemento superior y, además, tu código HTML podría contener dos o más elementos hermanos (en tu caso solo tienes uno, pero podrías tener más) y en ese caso no tendría lógica la función.

Comment: Una pequeña aclaración, si existe una función que convierte texto a nodos `insertAdjacentHTML`. Lamentablemente los inserta directamente sin retornar los nodos resultantes

Comment: @Yussef, para poder usar `insertAdjacentHTML()` debes proporcionar un nodo contenedor y eso tendría exactamente el mismo efecto colateral que usar `innerHTML`: la necesidad de usar un elemento contenedor. Y, de nuevo, debes usar `firstChild` (por ejemplo) para acceder al elemento creado y, en caso de que sean varios hermanos, otra vez pierde sentido.

Comment: El nodo contenedor en el ejemplo del OP es `document.body`, y en efecto, en la práctica sería lo mismo que usar innerHTML, estamos 100% de acuerdo de la inutilidad del mismo para el problema en cuestión. Mi comentario anterior, es solo una pequeñísima acotación, de que si es posible crear un nodo a partir de un texto.

Comment: En el ejemplo del OP no hay nodo contenedor. Presupone que su variable `code` es directamente el nodo `<p>` de su cadena de caracteres. Lo que posteriormente intenta es hacer una llamada a `document.body.appendChild(code);` que falla (por los motivos explicados en mi respuesta) y nunca se agrega al documento. Pero incluso si funcionara su código, `body` no se consideraría su nodo contenedor (el nodo que debe contener el HTML para que puedan generarse los elementos `Element`), si no su padre.

Answer (score 2):

Otra alternativa, usando [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)

```js
var code = '<p class="c1">Hola mundo</p>';

const doc1 = new DOMParser().parseFromString(code, "text/html").body.firstChild;

doc1.classList.add("rojo");
document.body.appendChild(doc1);
```

```css
.rojo{
  color:red
}
```

Comment: Imagino que serás consciente que estás creando una instancia de un [`HTMLDocument`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDocument) cuando llamas a `parseFromString()`. Es como matar moscas a cañonazos (es, a grandes rasgos, como si crearas una página web completa para agregar un único elemento a ella) y, además, con `.body` estás apuntando al elemento padre del párrafo `<p>` de la cadena y no al párrafo en sí, con lo que estás cambiando la clase al `<body>`. Lo habitual es crear únicamente un elemento de tipo `HTMLElement` contenedor con un `document.createElement()`.

Comment: Volvemos a estar de acuerdo, la pregunta ha sido respondida por ti a la perfección. Solo quise presentar un modo alternativo que puede servir a otro casos de uso. Sobre el tema del body, gracias por alertarme, lo he corregido